# Difference between distributed systems and non distributed systems..?

Tags: system, distributed

Can someone please explain to me the difference between distributed and non-distributed systems in simple terms...? with any example..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A distributed system is a backend infrastructure where different functionalities are split among different servers. It is also called microservices architecture.

This way if a server is down the functionality can still operate because of the multiple instances.

The opposite of a distributed system is a monolithic one, where everything is centralized and where, you can understand, if a server (the server) goes down, everything goes does.

This kind of distributed system is used to scale backend capabilities and make them fault tolerent.

You can watch GauravSen on youtube for more infos.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed system project made in one system and it can be access or used in another system
Example:
I have a database in my system, my friends have accessed to use in their system at multiple places.

Undistributed System you can use only in your system.